# angular infinite scrolling From REST API in abstract state

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, cordova

I'm working on application in cordova using angularjs for coding and used  [infinitescroll for angular](http://sroze.github.io/ngInfiniteScroll/demo_async.html) for scrolling remote API call.

Now my question is how i can use this plugin  with in click event for an button.

Example: I have to type a **searchtext** and i should pass that via API to get details.

I have to get first 10 elements in an array after it reaches to the 10th element again i should call API for more results .

below snippet is the code what i wrote so far for the abstract view.
**app.js**

```js
.state("sidemenu", {
        url: "/sidemenu",
        abstract: true,
        templateUrl: "app/templates/view-SideMenu.html",
        controller: "sidemenuCtrl"
    })
    
    
       .state("sidemenu.networkDetail", {
             url: "/networkDetail",
             templateUrl: "app/templates/view-networkDetail.html",
             controller: "networkDetailCtrl"
         })
```

Currently i'm able to get the list and working scrolling  with following $urlRouterProvider.
 **$urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/networkDetail")**

but when i tried the same with 
  **$urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/sidemenu/networkDetail")**

only first 5 elements will appear and to load next 5 data it is not scrolling from mobile side.

the functionality i used for scrolling are:

```js
   $scope.searchText = '';
       var requestScrollData =function() {
            this.items= [],
            this.busy=false
        }

        var ArraySize = {
            size: 0,
            total: ''
        }

        var getRequestData = function (index) {
            if ($scope.searchText === "") {
                console.log("Please input some text...");
            }
            else {
                return {
                    method: 'POST',
                    url: searchURL,
                    headers: {
                        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + $localstorage.get('access_token', '{}'),
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                    },
                    data: {
                        "start": index.toString(),
                        "length": "5"
                    }

                }
            }
         
        };

    requestScrollData.prototype.nextPage = function () {
            if (this.busy) return;
           this.busy = true;

            if (ArraySize.total === this.items.length) {
                console.log('no more items to load');
                ArraySize.size = this.items.length;
                return requestScrollData;
            }
            else {
                $http(getRequestData(ArraySize.size)).then(function (responseData) {
                    ArraySize.total = responseData.data.total;
                    var items = responseData.data.data;
                    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
                        this.items.push(items[i]);
                    }
                    ArraySize.size =this.items.length;
                    this.busy = false;
                }.bind(this));
                return requestScrollData;
            }
      

        };
 $scope.getData = function () {
  
        $scope.scrolling = new requestScrollData();
        $scope.scrolling.nextPage();
}
```

and html part is ..

```html
   <div infinite-scroll='scrolling.nextPage()' infinite-scroll-disabled='scrolling.busy' infinite-scroll-distance='0'>
        <div  ng-repeat="item in scrolling.items track by $index">
            
            
           {{item}}
        </div>
        <div  ng-show='scrolling.busy'><h4 style="color:darkgray;text-align:center"><i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;Loading data...</h4></div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on ngInfiniteScroll [documentation](http://sroze.github.io/ngInfiniteScroll/documentation.html), there is an attribute called `infinite-scroll-listen-for-event`

> **infinite-scroll-listen-for-event** (optional) - {string} - The name of
>   an event that, when received, will cause the scroll position check to
>   be re-run. This is useful if you need to manually trigger the scroll
>   handler, for instance if your items have been filtered or modified
>   without altering the collection.

So you could emit an event when button clicked, and pass the event name to `infinite-scroll-listen-for-event`

```
<div infinite-scroll='scrolling.nextPage()' 
     infinite-scroll-listen-for-event='RERUN_INFINITE_SCROLL'>
</div>

<button ng-click="btnClick()"></button>

//in controller
$scope.btnClick = function(){
    $scope.$emit('RERUN_INFINITE_SCROLL')
}
```

Comment: HI i tried but no result:( one more thing i found today  the view i'm rendering in abstract page. ie.,. i'm clubbing with abstract view ... it works fine with single page with no abstract view